# How to go to wifi settings for non-visible wifi networks in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: settings

I would like to reach the wifi settings for my saved connections but I seem to be unable to find them. When I go to the wifi settings it only shows settings for wifi connections that are currently visible.

I've been a been a simple ubuntu user for about 10 years now and never had such problems until I recently upgraded to 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option menu (represented by 3 lines) next to the window buttons in Wi-Fi settings window. There displayed an option called **Known Wi-fi Networks** for saved connections.

Comment: This answer does not appear to work for Ubuntu 22.04.